# AWS + Node/Express: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' for <img>

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, amazon-s3, cross-domain

I am hosting a node/express app at `http://www.my-example.com` and all my static contents (images, css, fonts) are served from a bucket named `assets` from Amazon S3. My images are present in `images` folder inside the bucket. I have defined following CORS for my bucket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://www.my-example.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I see that,

1. The server responds with `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/assets/images/... no access control origin header is present`
2. This server response is only present for images requested through `img` tag in html and not for any other static contents (css/fonts in headers etc)
3. And, images are still rendered correctly on my app.

Why is the server selectively sending Cross Origin response for images only? Do I need to change my express app to send `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"` header (in spite of configuring S3 bucket) ?

**Edit**

```
Request URL: https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/3dthon/images/social/icons/twitter.png
Request Method: Head
Status: 200
```

Here is the request and response headers:

```
Host: s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:37.0)   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://www.3dthon.com/
Origin: http://www.3dthon.com
Connection: keep-alive
```

And

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 3447
Content-Type: image/png
Date: Thu, 14 May 2015 16:20:09 GMT
Etag: "22705eae93b8bbe50f5c81bdf4bac99d"
Last-Modified: Thu, 13 Mar 2014 19:09:21 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
x-amz-id-2:   wrI2iITNNyruw91x1kHbvCtpHqCIbDumjpB/9BjK04EGmXp7NM5sGrOrxhj7Iv95nSx0Tt9wGiQ=x-amz-request-id: 9B840AA64CD6B3D2
```

Comment: You say your site is at my-example.com, but the allowed origin is www.my-example.com. Is this mismatch of domains a typo?

Comment: I'm sorry, a typo. Edited the question

Comment: Everything seems OK here. You shouldn't need to change your express app. Most likely is that your Amazon CORS configuration is wrong, can you post the entire cors config? Your rule should be wrapped in a <CORSConfiguration> element

Comment: I've edited the question to include entire CORSConfiguration element

Comment: That configuration looks fine, I can't see anything wrong with it. Browsers don't require CORS for <img> resources so that's why they're loading but the fonts aren't.
You could double check the CORS config to make sure it's saved on your S3 bucket properly?
Otherwise post the exact s3 url, or the exact request and error response from your browser's network trace (with all HTTP headers)

Comment: Any update on this? I got the same issue, no error in localhost, strange.